# Getting list of only vector layers using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I need a list containing all the vector layers in a QGIS session. I have this code to get all layers, how can I put a filter to get only vector layers?

```
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a list comprehension and filter only vector layers:

```
layers = [l for l in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values() if l.type() == QgsVectorLayer.VectorLayer]
```